# Scheme - how do i make this print true or false when it finds a specific value?

Tags: list, scheme

im making a solitaire game and to start off I'm making a function which provides either true or false if the given value on the card is valid as shown in the lists:

```
(define (card? val) 
(cond
[(list? (member(car val) (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 #\J #\K #\Q))) #t]
[(list? (member(cdr val) (#\H #\S #\C #\D))) #t]
[else #f]))
```

so here, if i input (card? 7 #\C) then id want it print

```
#true
#true
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please try to explain what you did and what does not work.  You call card? with 2 parameters and define it with arity 1.  It's not you who thought what you wrote.

Comment: "`val` is a valid card if `(member(car val) (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 #\J #\K #\Q))` is a list, *or* if `(member(cdr val) (#\H #\S #\C #\D))` is a list; otherwise it isn't". Doesn't sound quite right. Work out the logic before you write any code.